# customized shell script can not be run

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc

I have wrote a shell script, show the script

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t proxy@PROXY -p 22022 "ssh me@REMOATE_MACHINE -p 22022"
```

And I put the script to `/opt/scripts/myscript.sh`, and `chmod u+x myscript.sh`. After that I added `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/scripts/myscript.sh` in `.bashrc`.

And then `source .bashrc`, but when I type `myscript.sh`, the terminal returned `myscript.sh: command not found`

And `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/opt/scripts/myscript.sh:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/bin:/bin:/opt/hadoop-2.6.4/bin:/opt/hadoop-2.6.4/sbin:/opt/hive-2.0.0-bin/bin
```

`/opt/scripts/myscript.sh` is in the `PATH`

How should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add the script itself to `$PATH`. Instead, you should add the directory containing the script to `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not be `/opt/scripts/myscript.sh`. It should be `/opt/scripts`. It is treating `/opt/scripts/myscript.sh` as a directory and using all the files in it, not itself. This can be achieved by the following commands;

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/scripts
export PATH
```